# LVL - A statement for: "if you didn't download from market then finish()"

Tags: android, authentication, google-play, strict, android-lvl

I need a simple statement with an "if condition" that does this: "if you didn't download from market then finish()".
If I understood well there are two types of control: I need that the control is done strictly everytime connecting to the Android market server,  storing data nowhere in the phone for further offline checks.
Thanks, as usual, to the Stack citizens!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement licensing as per the [Application Licensing Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) and use the [StrictPolicy](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#StrictPolicy) detailed under [policies](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#impl-Policy).

StrictPolicy does not allow the caching of responses and I would think carefully about whether it is a good idea to demand that your users are online to use your application.

Comment: Yes, I need strict policy (for reasons that are off-topic). I imported on the code all the packages, but I don't know how to implement the requested if clause...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what David suggested, you could also watch for the `ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED` response code.

`ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED` — the application (package name) was not recognized by Android Market. Do not retry the license check. Can indicate that the application was not published through Android Market or that there is an development error in the licensing implementation.

Also, David makes a good point. Apps are guaranteed to fail communicating with the licensing server from time to time. This could drive your users mad.